# knockout.js 1.3.0 beta, jquery templates, and IE9 object doesn't support property or method

Tags: internet-explorer-9, knockout.js, jquery-templates

I am not what what is going on but I keep getting these weird errors.

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'template' 
knockout-1.3.0beta.debug.js, line 2946 character 17

precompiled = jQuery['template'](null, templateText);

SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'tmpl' 
knockout-1.3.0beta.debug.js, line 2928 character 17
```

I just can't pin point exactly why.  It works in Firefox, and I have used these same files before on another project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a full trial and error it looks to be caused by this line.

```
ko.mapping.updateFromJS(app.viewModel.members.breadCrumbs, breadCrumb);
```

I updated it to.

```
app.viewModel.members.breadCrumbs(ko.mapping.fromJS(breadCrumbs)());
```

It looks like my mapping file was off in version or something.

Answer (score 0):

this error usually occurs if variable/Function has the same name as a HTML ID. this error is not created in firefox.